# How to prevent loss of mavros msg packets?

Tags: quadcopter, ros

I am working with Pixhawk 2.1 cube, using telemetry module and mavros to establish communication between vehicle and companion computer. I am using rostopic echo to save /mavros/local_position/pose msg to a csv file. While working in sitl there is loss-less transmission of data. But when I connect to real vehicle there is huge loss of data and very few data points gets stored in csv file.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: what are the differences between the two setups?

Comment: Telemetry is used for communication between companion computer and real vehicle, whereas direct connection is used in software in the loop setup